# How do I properly "AS" a column that has the "LOWER" function applied, so as to refer to it in a wrapping "SELECT", in BigQuery SQL syntax?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to find the total word count of a given word in the publicly accessible BigQuery database on "shakespeare" (under samples -> shakespeare, also known as `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`).

The schema looks like this:

```
Field name | Type     | Mode      |  Description
---------------------------------------------------
word       | STRING   | REQUIRED  | A single unique word (where whitespace is the delimiter) extracted from a corpus.
word_count | INTEGER  | REQUIRED  | The number of times this word appears in this corpus.
corpus     | STRING   | REQUIRED  | The work from which this word was extracted.
corpus_date| INTEGER  | REQUIRED  | The year in which this corpus was published.
```

I have successfully combined all words, lowercased, across all values of `corpus`, and then combined all `corpus` instances into a new column, `found_in`, while also `SUM`ing their word counts into the column `total_word_count`.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT corpus) AS found_in,
  LOWER(word),
  SUM(word_count) AS total_word_count
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
GROUP BY
  LOWER(word)
ORDER BY
  total_word_count DESC
LIMIT
  1000
```

The output columns are

```
Row     found_in    f0_     total_word_count
```

My issue is renaming the `f0_` column. This is an issue because I'd like to wrap this whole thing in another query, so I can do something like `SELECT * FROM {{that previous query}} WHERE word="thou"`.

What I don't understand is

1. How to reference "word," in my `WHERE` clause.
2. How to name the `LOWER(word)` portion of my primary query, as I did for `STRING_AGG` and (SUM) (using `AS`).

I tried the following:

```
SELECT
* 
FROM
(
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT corpus) AS found_in,
  LOWER(word),
  SUM(word_count) AS total_word_count
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
GROUP BY
  LOWER(word)
ORDER BY
  total_word_count DESC
LIMIT
  1000
)
WHERE word = 'thou'
```

However, I got an error on the final line: `Unrecognized name: word`.

So, I tried to use `AS`:

```
SELECT
* 
FROM
(
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(DISTINCT corpus) AS found_in,
  LOWER(word) AS lowered_word,
  SUM(word_count) AS total_word_count
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
GROUP BY
  LOWER(word)
ORDER BY
  total_word_count DESC
LIMIT
  1000
)
WHERE word = 'and'
```

But then I got the error `SELECT list expression references column word which is neither grouped nor aggregated`, on the line with `LOWER(word)`.

This is confusing to me, because I see `word` referenced by the `GROUP BY`.

**How can I properly refer to LOWER(word) so as to refer to it in a secondary querty?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT corpus) AS found_in,
             LOWER(word) AS lowered_word,
             SUM(word_count) AS total_word_count
      FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
      GROUP BY lowered_word
      ORDER BY total_word_count DESC
      LIMIT 1000
     ) w
WHERE lowered_word = 'and';
```

Notes:

- There is nothing called `word` produced by the subquery, so use `lowered_word` for the outer comparison.
- You can aggregate in BigQuery by column aliases.
- The `LIMIT` in the subquery seems arbitrary.  I don't think it improves performance or lowers the cost of the query.

Comment: Perfect! Out of curiosity, what does the `w` at the end of the inner query do?

Comment: @CalebJay . . . It is a table alias, so it assigns a "name" to the subquery.  Some databases require them and I always include one.